# Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
root@staging:~# sudo systemctl unmask docker
Removed /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.
root@staging:~# sudo systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I needed to run this to solve a docker issue. Docker kept crashing after 1-2 hours after I run docker-compose up. So I tried to follow the steps provided here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163450/unable-to-docker-compose-up-any-project

When I run this, I get:

```
root@staging:~# start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then, when logging by running systemctl status docker.service:

```
docker.service - LSB: Create lightweight, portable, self-sufficient containers.
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/docker; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-09-08 18:13:30 UTC; 1min 37s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 329588 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/docker start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 08 18:13:30 staging.shane.com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Create lightweight, portable, self-sufficient containers....
Sep 08 18:13:30 staging.shane.com docker[329588]:  * /usr/bin/dockerd not present or not executable
Sep 08 18:13:30 staging.shane.com systemd[1]: docker.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 08 18:13:30 staging.shane.com systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 08 18:13:30 staging.shane.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Create lightweight, portable, self-sufficient containers..
```

And the other log:

```
    Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d107a0b785af: port 1(veth2eb79a3) entered blocking state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d107a0b785af: port 1(veth2eb79a3) entered forwarding state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: eth2: renamed from vetha6ad44f
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: veth87721c2: Gained carrier
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth87721c2: link becomes ready
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d86eed067d4f: port 1(veth87721c2) entered blocking state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d86eed067d4f: port 1(veth87721c2) entered forwarding state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: veth8794b2b: Lost carrier
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-5ee6c619ebc6: port 3(veth8794b2b) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: veth9694d7a: renamed from eth0
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-udevd[332558]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex a>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com networkd-dispatcher[463]: WARNING:Unknown index 780021 seen, reloading interface list
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-udevd[332558]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex a>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: veth8794b2b: Link DOWN
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-5ee6c619ebc6: port 3(veth8794b2b) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: device veth8794b2b left promiscuous mode
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-5ee6c619ebc6: port 3(veth8794b2b) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: rtnl: received neighbor for link '780022' we don't know about, ig>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: rtnl: received neighbor for link '780022' we don't know about, ig>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: veth2eb79a3: Lost carrier
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d107a0b785af: port 1(veth2eb79a3) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: veth8058d46: renamed from eth1
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-udevd[332558]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex a>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com networkd-dispatcher[463]: WARNING:Unknown index 780023 seen, reloading interface list
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: veth2eb79a3: Link DOWN
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d107a0b785af: port 1(veth2eb79a3) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: device veth2eb79a3 left promiscuous mode
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d107a0b785af: port 1(veth2eb79a3) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: rtnl: received neighbor for link '780024' we don't know about, ig>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: rtnl: received neighbor for link '780024' we don't know about, ig>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-udevd[332558]: veth8058d46: Failed to get link config: No such device
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: veth87721c2: Lost carrier
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d86eed067d4f: port 1(veth87721c2) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: vetha6ad44f: renamed from eth2
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-udevd[332558]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex a>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com networkd-dispatcher[463]: WARNING:Unknown index 780025 seen, reloading interface list
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: veth87721c2: Link DOWN
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d86eed067d4f: port 1(veth87721c2) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: device veth87721c2 left promiscuous mode
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com kernel: br-d86eed067d4f: port 1(veth87721c2) entered disabled state
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: rtnl: received neighbor for link '780026' we don't know about, ig>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: rtnl: received neighbor for link '780026' we don't know about, ig>
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-udevd[332558]: vetha6ad44f: Failed to get link config: No such device
Sep 08 18:17:13 staging.shane.com systemd-networkd[809323]: br-d107a0b785af: Lost carrier
Sep 08 18:17:20 staging.shane.com sshd[333537]: Unable to negotiate with 141.98.12.129 port 58900: no matching key exchange m>
Sep 08 18:17:30 staging.shane.com sshd[333542]: Unable to negotiate with 141.98.12.129 port 57548: no matching key exchange m>
```

Comment: Your installation of docker is broken. Remove it and reinstall the official docker packages from the docker web site.

Comment: I was thinking that too. Is there a tutorial that shows you how to do this properly?

Comment: Go to the web site and follow the instructions.

Comment: I only installed docker-compose initially. Do I just need to install docker? Do I need to uninstall docker-compose and docker?

Comment: I didn't say anything about docker-compose.